# How to disable changing GoJS diagram after page refreshing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gojs

My question will be simple. I'm new in GoJS diagrams building.
And I have some static GoJS diagram in my web app page. 
But after I refresh page, diagram changes it's form. It still consists of the same blocks I have before refreshing but it only changes the form.

How could I disable it? I need the same form of diagram after refreshing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using **ForceDirectedLayout**? I believe that is the only standard Layout with nondeterministic behavior, due to its usage of **Math.random**.

If so, set http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/ForceDirectedLayout.html#randomNumberGenerator to null.

The general alternative is to save locations for all of the nodes and use a Binding on **Node.location**.